# SQL command search

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Table] where Col1 like 
                      %@astr% or Col2 like %@astr% or Col3 like %@astr%)", con);        
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@astr", st);
```

What is wrong with the command above?
I got error message "near the @astr".

Comment: Try removing `)` at the end in your sql query, use this `like %@astr%`

Comment: oh! thank you! 3 hours and i cannot even figure it out

Comment: No worries, happens in a busy day :-)

Comment: Sir! It seems the % cannot go with @..
Because after i remove the ), I still got that problem.
What should I do?

Comment: I added answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify wild characters (`%`) in your variable, remove wild characters in query.

```
st = string.Format("%{0}%", st); // in case your search string don't have wild characters..
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Table] where Col1 like 
                      %@astr% or Col2 like @astr or Col3 like @astr)", con);        
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@astr", st);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quotes around your search strings missing and one parentheses too many:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  @"select * from [Table] 
    where Col1 like '%' || @astr || '%' 
       or Col2 like '%' || @astr || '%' 
       or Col3 like '%' || @astr || '%'", con);
```

Comment: is that || ?
I've never seen this inside a SQL query

Comment: It is the standard SQL operator to concatenate strings, e.g. `'hello ' || 'world'`. Almost all DBMS support this syntax. There are exceptions, though. I think SQL Server uses the non-standard `+` for instance. And in MySQL it may depend on some setting and one might have to use `CONCAT` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If astr is an string. you can try this.

```
string astr = "ABC";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Table] where Col1 like %" + astr + "% or Col2 like %" + astr + "% or Col3 like %" + astr + "%", con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@astr", st);
```